# Avoid document.addEventListener to automatically prevent default on Meteor

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

I'm using Meteor and Cordova to develop an Android app. I need to handle the backbutton event so the slideout closes if it is open, or continues with default execution is slideout is closed:

```
document.addEventListener('backbutton', function (e) {
  if (slideout.isOpen()) {
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()
    slideout.close()
  }
})
```

This code is inside `Template.mainLayout.onRendered` on main layout.

Also tried reducing the code to just

```
document.addEventListener('backbutton', function(){})
```

and this leads to absolutely no functionality for the backbutton.

Comment: Are you sure there is an event called backbutton?

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton The event gets called and everything functions except the propagation.

Comment: So the event is not even fired or it is definitely fired but prevented? How did you make sure to know about this status?

Comment: In the documentation I linked, it explains the event is overriden. I found a workaround by adding the expected functionality in the `else` which in this case was `history.back()`